# Angular 2 Kendo UI Grid Pagination Position

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

How do you configure the pagination of the grid let say the total page number e.g: 5 of 8 to be shown before the grid.

Achieved it on previous version of Kendo Grid using .insertBefore(.k-grid-content) something like that. But have no idea on Angular 2. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use this field for your component where you

```
import { SortDescriptor, orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { GridComponent, GridDataResult, DataStateChangeEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';



private pageSizesNumber: boolean = true;
private buttonCount: number = 5;
private pageSize: number = 10;
```

and on html side use

```
<kendo-grid [data]="view | async"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [skip]="skip"
    [pageable]="{
        buttonCount: buttonCount,
        info: info,
        type: type,
        pageSizes: [5,10,20,25,50,100],
        previousNext: previousNext
    }"
    [sortable]="true"
    [sort]="sort"
    class="input-xs">
    "Your grid column"
 </kendo-grid>
```